# Angular Material - how to set input to red

Tags: angular, angular-material

For below angular code, the mat-form will automatically display in red if it does not fill in any value.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter your email" [formControl]="email" required>
</mat-form-field>
```

However, for below case, I added onblur to validate by typescript `checkOrderNo()` method, but the mat-form-field does not change to red....

Please help

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [blur]="checkOrderNo()" placeholder="Enter your order no" [formControl]="orderno">
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
checkOrderNo(): boolean {
  if (this.orderno > 1000001) {return false;}
  else {return true;}
}
```

Comment: What do you expect values `true` or `false` to even do here?

Comment: ...further more, what you want is a custom error state matcher which Angular Material has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two CSS classes that will contain the color you want, for instance :

```
.red {
   color:red;
}
.green {
   color:green;       
}
```

Then you can use **ng-class** with conditions this way :

```
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter your order no" [formControl]="orderno" 
                        ng-class="{red: (checkOrderNo()), green: (!checkOrderNo())}"/>
```

This should work.

Comment: The correct input should be `[ngClass]="{'class-1': true, ...}"`